# IntelliJ align array values to right margin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have array with "next line char" inside like on picture:

[image]

When I rearrange code the array / methods and other lines which have "next line char" not changes.

What I need to do to have code formatted like on picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable this option:
[image: Intellij]

I have IDEA 15, but it should be available in other versions too.